# accuracy is not increasing in classification images

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, classification, bayesian, conv-neural-network

I try to implement the classification of images with bayesian CNN using dropout.
I have defined two classes:

1. with dropout for the training phase
2. without dropout for the test(Don’t drop out on testing? to be confirmed please)

When I started the program I remade that the train/test accuracy remain stable they don’t increase. I don’t see what the problem is.
I don’t know if it’s because of convolution and pooling layer parameters or what? Any idea please.

```
class Net(nn.Module):
   
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5, padding=2)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5, padding=2)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 8 * 8, 1024)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 192 * 8 * 8)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

```
            # Lenet with MCDO
    class Net_MCDO(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Net_MCDO, self).__init__()
            self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5, padding=2)
            self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
            self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 192, 5, padding=2)
            self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 8 * 8, 120)
            self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
            self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)
            self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.3)

    def forward(self, x):
            x = self.pool(self.dropout(self.conv1(x)))
            x = self.pool(self.dropout(self.conv2(x)))
            x = x.view(-1, 192 * 8 * 8)
            x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
            x = F.relu(self.fc2(self.dropout(x)))
            x = F.softmax(self.fc3(self.dropout(x)),dim=1)
            return x
```

```
    net=Net()
    mcdo=Net_MCDO()
    
    CE = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    learning_rate=0.001
    optimizer=optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, momentum=0.9)
    epoch_num = 30
    train_accuracies=np.zeros(epoch_num)
    test_accuracies=np.zeros(epoch_num)
    for epoch in range(epoch_num):
        average_loss = 0.0
        total=0
        success=0
        
        for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
            inputs, labels = data
            inputs, labels = Variable(inputs), Variable(labels)
            
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = mcdo(inputs)
            loss=CE(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
 
            average_loss += loss.item()
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
            total += labels.size(0)
            success += (predicted==labels.data).sum()
 
        train_accuracy = 100.0*success/total
        succes=0
        total=0

        for (inputs, labels) in testloader:
            inputs, labels = Variable(inputs), Variable(labels)
            outputs = net(inputs)
            _,predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
            total += labels.size(0)
            success += (predicted==labels.data).sum()

        test_accuracy = 100.0*success/total
        print(u"epoch{}, average_loss{}, train_accuracy{},                 
          test_accuracy{}".format(
          epoch,
          average_loss/n_batches,
          train_accuracy,
          100*success/total
          ))
            #save
            train_accuracies[epoch] = train_accuracy
            test_accuracies[epoch] = 100.0*success/total

    plt.plot(np.arange(1, epoch_num+1), train_accuracies)
    plt.plot(np.arange(1, epoch_num+1), test_accuracies)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Done, I think it's more clear now, thank you

Comment: What is `CE` ? you don't show how you initialize it.

Comment: I also don't understand why you use `mcdo` with train data and `net` with test data? They are initialized independently, how does training one will improve the other?

Comment: I just edited it,

Comment: Yea, I realized that it doesn't make any sense,  I didn't know how to test the model without dropout using one model,,

Comment: I just answered it, look below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pytorch merges `Softmax` inside the `CrossEntroplyLoss` for numerical stability (and better training). So you should remove the softmax layer of your models. (check the documentation here: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#crossentropyloss). Keeping the `Sofmax` layer in your model will lead to slower training and possibly worse metrics, that is because you are *squashing* the gradient twice, thus the weight update is a lot less significant.

Change your code to:

```
 class Net_MCDO(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Net_MCDO, self).__init__()
            self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5, padding=2)
            self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
            self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 192, 5, padding=2)
            self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 8 * 8, 120)
            self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
            self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)
            self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.3)

    def forward(self, x):
            x = self.pool(F.relu(self.dropout(self.conv1(x))))  # recommended to add the relu
            x = self.pool(F.relu(self.dropout(self.conv2(x))))  # recommended to add the relu
            x = x.view(-1, 192 * 8 * 8)
            x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
            x = F.relu(self.fc2(self.dropout(x)))
            x = self.fc3(self.dropout(x)) # no activation function needed for the last layer
            return x
```

Furthermore, I would recommend you using an activation function, such as `ReLU()` after every conv or linear layer. Otherwise you are just performing a bunch of linear operations that could be learned in one single layer.

I hope that helps =)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right: Dont use dropout (nor batchnorm) when testing. But you dont have to create to different models for that. You can choose between a train-mode and a test-mode. Just create one model, for example 'net':

```
# when training
outputs = net.train()(inputs)

# when testing:
outputs = net.eval()(inputs)
```

But you shouldnt really use dropout with conv-layers anyways. Just on the dense layers at the end. That could be the reason why it is not improving.
And you architecture is quite small. How big are you images? If they are over 32x32 you can try and add one more layer. You can also try to start with a learning rate about 0.001 and then deviding it by two every time the accuracy doesnt improve for some epochs. Hope this will help you :)

**Edit**
I just saw that you are missing the relu activations on the second model (with dropout), that should cause problems.

Comment: Yes, I am using 32x32 it's the Cifar10 images, 
How could I choose between a train-mode and a test-mode? I create just one model (with dropout ) what should I do after that? am new in deep learning and PyTorch all, thank you

Comment: I showed it in my answer: When you have your one model, ie ```model = Model()```
then in train mode you do ```outputs = model.train()(inputs)``` and when you want to test you do ```outputs = model.eval()(inputs)```, thats it!
Eval stands for "evaluation", so dropout will be ignored automatically

Comment: Okay am gonna see, Thank you so much